# Invoking one jenkins job from multiple repos

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to create a jenkins CI job (Lets name is check-validate-job)  which will be triggered whenever a PR is created .
I have 7 git repos ,the git repos are just yaml files with cucumber tests .
I want to **create one jenkins CI job** for all the repos (Which just runs a simple mvn install command )  which will be triggered whenever a PR is raised on any one repo .

Example :
Lets say I have PR's raised to repo A,B,C , then it should trigger a Jenkins JOB check-validate-job . I don't want to create multiple jenkins job .

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here is to have a separate polling job that runs every couple of minutes and polls all of your repos to see if there have been any new PRs raised. If there is, you can recursively schedule builds into your main job and change the status of each PR so that it doesn't get scheduled again unless there is a new commit (or whatever logic you want to use). The builds can contain the repo and PR/branch name as parameters, which your main job can use to checkout and build as needed. This way, you will only have 2 jobs, one to get the necessary PRs and schedule them into your main build, and another to do the actual building.